# How can I insert current URL in a 'post action' Facebook JavaScript Function

Tags: function, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am able to post the action below to facebook. What I would like to do now is to automatically insert the current page URL into MYURL. Then I can put this code in an external file rather than having to manually insert the url and to have it on every page. I am new to JavaScript (it took me a long time to the code below together). I have searched this to death and cannot find a way to do this. I would be very grateful for any help.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function postRead()
    {

FB.api('/me/namespace:action&object=http://MYURL','post',  function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });

FB.api('/me/namespace:action&object=http://MYURL','post',  function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
              } else {
                 document.getElementById("postlink").innerHTML="Posted!";

              }
        });

   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
              } else {
                 document.getElementById("postlink").innerHTML="Posted!";

              }
        });
    }   


</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display Javascript variable inside a javascript?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12180212/how-to-display-javascript-variable-inside-a-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out thanks to this post -> [strip characters from url on javascript 'onclick'-command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782120/strip-characters-from-url-on-javascript-onclick-command). UnfortunI can't vote it up because I have no reputation, which is a shame.

The answer code is in double stars, which is meant to be emboldened sorry.

```
function postRead()
    {
FB.api('/me/namespace:action&object='**+encodeURIComponent(location.href)**,'post', function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
        FB.login(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
     FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
     });

FB.api('/me/namespace:action&object='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'post', function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occured');
              } else {
                 document.getElementById("postlink").innerHTML="Posted!";

              }
        });

   } else {
     console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 });
              } else {
                 document.getElementById("postlink").innerHTML="Posted!";

              }
        });
    }
```